# Get integer value of the current year in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date

I need to determine the current year in Java as an integer. I could just use `java.util.Date()`, but it is deprecated.

Comment: No, `java.util.Date` is *not* deprecated, not as of Java 8. Some of its methods are deprecated but not the entire class. But you should avoid both `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` as they are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Instead use either [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (in Java 8) or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Answer (score 798, accepted):

For Java 8 onwards:

```
int year = Year.now().getValue();
```

For older version of Java:

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: Upon seeing your answer, Calendar would be a fine object to use. I was looking for a one-liner and I didn't think Calendar would have that for me. Proven wrong I am! Thanks!

Comment: What about concurrency, what if other thread/piece of library code changes current time? Wouldn't it be reasonable to modify it to something like: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); synchronized (c) {c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); return c.get(Calendar.YEAR);}

Comment: This returns a different value in different versions of Android.  I am comparing Android v4.1.2 with v4.2.1 .

Comment: I removed my SIM card from the phone with 4.1.2.  So the network was not able to update the Date and Time on the phone.  Consequently the phone was stuck in 2012.  Looks like this is not a bug in 4.1.2 .

Comment: @ycnix There's no concurrency issue with the code, so there is no need to make it more compilcated. `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)`  is atomic in regards to the clock being changed externally, and doing `synchronized(c)` on a newly instance of a local variable would anyhow be very pointless here.

Comment: `import java.util.Calendar`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes used here are now legacy, supplanted by the vastly improved java.time classes.

Comment: It may be interesting to add the new way of doing it (detailed in the answer below) in Java 8.

Comment: `import java.time` for `Year`

Answer (score 188):

Using Java 8's time API (assuming you are happy to get the year in your system's default time zone), you could use [the `Year::now` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#now--):

```
int year = Year.now().getValue();
```

Comment: I suggest always passing the optional `ZoneId` argument to `now` rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default zone (that can change at any moment during runtime!).

Comment: Which looks likes this BTW:
`int year = Year.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).getValue();`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#now--

Answer (score 29):

This simplest (using Calendar, sorry) is:

```
 int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

There is also the new [Date and Time API JSR](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/), as well as [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This returns a different value in different versions of Android. I am comparing Android v4.1.2 with v4.2.1 .

Comment: @toobsco42 - try googling for 'android calendar.year bug'

Comment: Hey @toolkit, I have been doing some research with no luck.  I was hoping for a more specific answer.

Comment: I removed my SIM card from the phone with 4.1.2. So the network was not able to update the Date and Time on the phone. Consequently the phone was stuck in 2012. Looks like this is not a bug in 4.1.2 .

Answer (score 18):

You can also use 2 methods from `java.time.YearMonth`( Since Java 8 ):

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
...
int year = YearMonth.now().getYear();
int month = YearMonth.now().getMonthValue();
```

Comment: You incorrectly duplicate [another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700141/642706) posted long ago. And you produce a month which is irrelevant to the Question. And you ignore the crucial issue of time zone. And your formatting is messy. I'm glad to see you participating in Stack Overflow. But this Answer is not good enough. Edit to correct its weaknesses and add more value beyond that already provided by the other Answers. Or delete your Answer before it collects down-votes. P.S. Super avatar icon!

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I've edited. link is a little bit different that my way

Answer (score 16):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now(  ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )  )
             .getYear()
```

## Time Zone

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28891864/642706) by [Raffi Khatchadourian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405326/raffi-khatchadourian) wisely shows how to use the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8. But that answer fails to address the critical issue of time zone in determining a date.

> int year = LocalDate.now().getYear();

That code depends on the JVM's current default time zone. The default zone is used in determining what today’s date is. Remember, for example, that in the moment after midnight in Paris the date in Montréal is still 'yesterday'.

So your results may vary by what machine it runs on, a user/admin changing the host OS time zone, or any Java code *at any moment* changing the JVM's current default. Better to specify the time zone.

By the way, always use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as [defined by the IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Never use the 3-4 letter codes that are neither standardized nor unique.

## java.time

Example in java.time of Java 8.

```
int year = ZonedDateTime.now(  ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )  ).getYear() ;
```

## Joda-Time

Some idea as above, but using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.7 library.

```
int year = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ).getYear() ;
```

## Incrementing/Decrementing Year

If your goal is to jump a year at a time, no need to extract the year number. Both Joda-Time and java.time have methods for adding/subtracting a year at a time. And those methods are smart, handling Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies.

Example in *java.time*.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    ZonedDateTime
    .now(  ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )  )
    .minusYears( 1 ) 
;
```

Example in Joda-Time 2.7.

```
DateTime oneYearAgo = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ).minusYears( 1 ) ;
```

Comment: All zone IDs for the lazy ones (as me): https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-display-all-zoneid-and-its-utc-offset/

Comment: @FBB I suggest the [Wikipedia page for the official IANA list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) of time zone names. **Beware: These zones change surprisingly often.** If you really want up-to-date info, download a fresh copy of [the `tzdata` data file](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) yourself. You can peruse the file. And you can replace an outdated tzdata in your Java implementation. Oracle provides an [updater tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) for their JVM.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to get the year from Calendar.

```
// year is stored as a static member
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: Calendar.YEAR is not the current year.

Comment: Calendar.YEAR is defined thus...

    public final static int YEAR = 1;

Comment: The get() API on Calendar gets the datum that is at the field specified by the constant. The year is located in the 1's field in the Calendar object! Calendar.getInstance() is getting the current date.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)

Comment: This returns a different value in different versions of Android. I am comparing Android v4.1.2 with v4.2.1 .

Comment: I removed my SIM card from the phone with 4.1.2. So the network was not able to update the Date and Time on the phone. Consequently the phone was stuck in 2012. Looks like this is not a bug in 4.1.2 .

Answer (score 10):

If you want the year of any date object, I used the following method:

```
public static int getYearFromDate(Date date) {
    int result = -1;
    if (date != null) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        result = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: result is 1970!

Answer (score 7):

Use the following code for java 8 :

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
int year = localDate.getYear();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
int date = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use Java 8's [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
//...
int year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
```

Comment: @AndrewT.,get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and it will work in Java 6 and 7 too.

Answer (score 4):

If your application is making heavy use of Date and Calendar objects, you really should use Joda Time, because `java.util.Date` is mutable. `java.util.Calendar` has performance problems when its fields get updated, and is clunky for datetime arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

As some people answered above:

If you want to use the variable later, better use:

```
int year;

year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

If you need the year for just a condition you better use:

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

For example using it in a do while that checks introduced year is not less than the current year-200 or more than the current year (Could be birth year):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner scannernumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    int year;

    /*Checks that the year is not higher than the current year, and not less than the current year - 200 years.*/

    do{
        System.out.print("Year (Between "+((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))-200)+" and "+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)+") : ");
        year = scannernumber.nextInt();
    }while(year < ((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))-200) || year > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing using Integer math without needing to instantiate a calendar:

```
return (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000/3600/24/365.25 +1970);
```

May be off for an hour or two at new year but I don't get the impression that is an issue?

Comment: are you working for apple, perhaps? http://www.macworld.com/article/2023580/ios-do-not-disturb-feature-oversleeps-on-new-year-s-day.html

Comment: wow, this is very heavy, I would suggest to keep it simple like cagcowboy has shown it.

Comment: This may not be the best in all circumstances, but it doesn't deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the above is worked. So After trying lot of solutions i found below one and it worked for me

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class Practice
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Date d=new Date();  
        int year=d.getYear();
        int currentYear=year+1900;    

        System.out.println(currentYear);

    }

}
```

Comment: That method is deprecated. And that terrible class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See modern solution in the [Answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700141/642706).

Comment: yeah but i was actively seeking for solution and tried many available solution and for me this one worked so i posted :)

Answer (score 0):

I may add that a simple way to get the current year as an integer is importing
java.time.LocalDate and, then:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
int yourVariable = LocalDate.now().getYear()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not bad. It’s already in a couple of the other answers, which is the only reason why I am not upvoting.

Answer (score -2):

In Java version 8+ can (advised to) use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library. [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) sets standard way to write dates: `YYYY-MM-DD` and `java.time.Instant` uses it, so (for `UTC`):

```
import java.time.Instant;
int myYear = Integer.parseInt(Instant.now().toString().substring(0,4));
```

P.S. just in case (and shorted for getting `String`, not `int`), using `Calendar` looks better and can be made zone-aware.

Comment: You are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. See simpler solution in [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700141/642706).

Answer (score -5):

I use special functions in my library to work with days/month/year ints -

```
int[] int_dmy( long timestamp ) // remember month is [0..11] !!!
{
  Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); cal.setTimeInMillis( timestamp );
  return new int[] { 
    cal.get( Calendar.DATE ), cal.get( Calendar.MONTH ), cal.get( Calendar.YEAR )
  };
};


int[] int_dmy( Date d ) { 
 ...
}
```