# Illegal pattern character 'T' when parsing a date string to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, iso8601

I have a date string and I want to parse it to normal date use the java Date API,the following is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date="2010-10-02T12:23:23Z";
    String pattern="yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    try {
        Date d=sdf.parse(date);
        System.out.println(d.getYear());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However I got an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'`

So I wonder if I have to split the string and parse it manually?

BTW, I have tried to add a single quote character on either side of the T:

```
String pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ";
```

It also does not work.

Comment: do you know what does this "T" means ? As far as I think the whole date along with the 'T' should be converted to the date (not skipping it through 'Single Quotes', but the thing we're missing is the parse pattern.

Comment: The `T` stands for *time* and is part of the [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for international date time formatting.

Comment: That's odd. Wrapping the `T` in single quotes worked for me (at least in terms of solving the parse error).

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use either `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant`. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 240, accepted):

#### Update for Java 8 and higher

You can now simply do `Instant.parse("2015-04-28T14:23:38.521Z")` and get the correct thing now, especially since you should be using `Instant` instead of the broken `java.util.Date` with the most recent versions of Java.

You should be using `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormatter` as well.

#### Original Answer:

> The explanation below is still valid as as what the format represents.
>   But it was written before Java 8 was ubiquitous so it uses the old
>   classes that you should not be using if you are using Java 8 or
>   higher.

#### This works with the input with the trailing `Z` as demonstrated:

> In the pattern the `T` is escaped with `'` on either side.
>
> The pattern for the `Z` at the end is actually `XXX` as documented
>   in the JavaDoc for `SimpleDateFormat`, it is just not very clear
>   on actually how to use it since `Z` is the marker for the old
>   `TimeZone` information as well.

#### [Q2597083.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q2597083.java)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Q2597083
{
    /**
     * All Dates are normalized to UTC, it is up the client code to convert to the appropriate TimeZone.
     */
    public static final TimeZone UTC;

    /**
     * @see <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations">Combined Date and Time Representations</a>
     */
    public static final String ISO_8601_24H_FULL_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";

    /**
     * 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
     */
    public static final Date BEGINNING_OF_TIME;

    /**
     * 292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z
     */
    public static final Date END_OF_TIME;

    static
    {
        UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        TimeZone.setDefault(UTC);
        final Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(UTC);
        c.set(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        BEGINNING_OF_TIME = c.getTime();
        c.setTime(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
        END_OF_TIME = c.getTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601_24H_FULL_FORMAT);
        sdf.setTimeZone(UTC);
        System.out.println("sdf.format(BEGINNING_OF_TIME) = " + sdf.format(BEGINNING_OF_TIME));
        System.out.println("sdf.format(END_OF_TIME) = " + sdf.format(END_OF_TIME));
        System.out.println("sdf.format(new Date()) = " + sdf.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println("sdf.parse(\"2015-04-28T14:23:38.521Z\") = " + sdf.parse("2015-04-28T14:23:38.521Z"));
        System.out.println("sdf.parse(\"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\") = " + sdf.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"));
        System.out.println("sdf.parse(\"292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z\") = " + sdf.parse("292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z"));
    }
}
```

#### Produces the following output:

```
sdf.format(BEGINNING_OF_TIME) = 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
sdf.format(END_OF_TIME) = 292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z
sdf.format(new Date()) = 2015-04-28T14:38:25.956Z
sdf.parse("2015-04-28T14:23:38.521Z") = Tue Apr 28 14:23:38 UTC 2015
sdf.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") = Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1
sdf.parse("292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z") = Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 UTC 292278994
```

Answer (score 31):

## tl;dr

Use `java.time.Instant` class to parse text in standard ISO 8601 format, representing a moment in UTC.

```
Instant.parse( "2010-10-02T12:23:23Z" )
```

## ISO 8601

That format is defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time string formats.

Both:

- [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html))
- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library

…use ISO 8601 formats by default for parsing and generating strings.

You should generally **avoid using the old java.util.Date**/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes as they are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. If required for interoperating, you can convert to and fro.

## java.time

Built into Java 8 and later is the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. Inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2010-10-02T12:23:23Z" );  // `Instant` is always in UTC.
```

Convert to the old class.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );  // Pass an `Instant` to the `from` method.
```

**Time Zone**

If needed, you can assign a time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); // Define a time zone rather than rely implicitly on JVM’s current default time zone.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );  // Assign a time zone adjustment from UTC.
```

Convert.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );  // Extract an `Instant` from the `ZonedDateTime` to pass to the `from` method.
```

## Joda-Time

UPDATE: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the *java.time* classes.

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.8.

```
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime_Utc = new DateTime( "2010-10-02T12:23:23Z" , DateTimeZone.UTC );  // Specifying a time zone to apply, rather than implicitly assigning the JVM’s current default.
```

Convert to old class. Note that the assigned time zone is lost in conversion, as j.u.Date cannot be assigned a time zone.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime_Utc.toDate(); // The `toDate` method converts to old class.
```

**Time Zone**

If needed, you can assign a time zone.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTime_Montreal = dateTime_Utc.withZone ( zone );
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android.]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: @AalapPatel Be aware that the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes. Both efforts are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

Comment: Thank you, I use it to get miliseconds from server returned UTC time and/or locale time and works well for me in this case..

Comment: Instant.parse needs min api level 26 in android

Comment: @NaveedAhmad See the bullets at bottom of Answer about *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse string to Timestamp with the following method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String timeStr = "2021-11-11T10:25:35+00:00";
    System.out.println(convertStringToTimestamp(timeStr));

}

static Timestamp convertStringToTimestamp(String dateAsString) {
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateAsString);
    final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    return Optional.ofNullable(offsetDateTime.toString())
            .map(value -> LocalDateTime.parse(value, dateTimeFormatter))
            .map(Timestamp::valueOf)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Avoid `Timestamp` if you can. If for JDBC [use `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/5772882). (2) Whether your conversion is correct depends. It also seems a bit more complicated than necessary.

Comment: If you do need an old-fashioned `Timestamp` for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time: `return Timestamp.from(OffsetDateTime.parse(dateAsString).toInstant());`. A bit simpler, isn’t it?

Comment: ['Z' is not the same as Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573)

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers above up-to-now and they are both long (and *tl;dr* too short IMHO), so I write summary from my experience starting to use new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library (applicable as noted in other answers to Java version 8+). [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) sets standard way to write dates: `YYYY-MM-DD` so the format of date-time is only as below (could be 0, 3, 6 or 9 digits for milliseconds) and no formatting string necessary:

```
import java.time.Instant;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date="2010-10-02T12:23:23Z";
    try {
        Instant myDate = Instant.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I did not need it, but as getting year is in code from the question, then:
it is trickier, cannot be done from `Instant` directly, can be done via `Calendar` in way of questions [Get integer value of the current year in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136419/get-integer-value-of-the-current-year-in-java) and [Converting java.time to Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779179/converting-java-time-to-calendar) but IMHO as format is fixed substring is more simple to use:

```
myDate.toString().substring(0,4);
```