# Cannot parse String into Date from Json, UnparsableDateException

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I have used this code to parse a String received from Json in Date Format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                                try{
                                    Date myDateConference = sdf.parse(jsonO.getString("myDateConference")); 
                                }
                                catch(ParseException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

The String of the date is something in this form `2012-08-02T00:00:00`

But I get this exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-08-02T00:00:00"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-date?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");`

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a T in your source String:

```
"2012-08-02<b>T</b>00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the format to

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```