# Converting java.time to Calendar

Tags: java, java-time

What is the simplest way of getting a `Calendar` object from a `java.time.Instant` or `java.time.ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: Judging by your reputation I suspect that you probably tested `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTimeInMillis(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());` so what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: And probably you also tried - `GregorianCalendar.from(zonedDateTime);`

Comment: @RohitJain I haven't tried that -- I didn't even remember `GregorianCalendar`. That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! I can't accept comments, though.

Comment: @Pshemo That is missing the zone. I need four lines to return a `Calendar` using that. I could one-line with the builder, but the line gets so long it's better broken off into four lines as well. Now, compared that, which I did use, to the solution that Rohit provided and you'll see what's wrong with it and why I asked.

Comment: @JBNizet 1) Yes. 2) I was not satisfied with the solution I came up with. 3) Javadoc is freely available, but finding a method going from `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` to `Calendar` by looking at `GregorianCalendar` is not something crossed my mind. It's non-obvious and I didn't find it on a google search. All of which you might have realized if you had actually tried to answer the question instead of blithely, and incorrectly, assuming it was trivial.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral That is what I suspected. I added my comment just so others could read your response and learn about what exactly you didn't like in this approach (since you didn't mention it in your question). And yes, Rohit's solution seem to be perfect here.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Getting a `Calendar` instant from `ZonedDateTime` is pretty straight-forward, provided you know that there exists a [`GregorianCalendar#from(ZonedDateTime)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from-java.time.ZonedDateTime-) method. There was a discussion in [Threeten-dev mail group](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/threeten-dev/2013-June/001476.html), about why that method is not in `Calendar` class. Not a very deep discussion though.

However, there is no direct way to convert from an `Instant` to `Calendar`. You've to have an intermediate state for that:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
Calendar cal1 = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
```

This is probably because, as evident from the table on [this oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html), an `Instant` maps to `Date` rather than a `Calendar`. Similarly, a `ZonedDateTime` maps to a `Calendar`.

Comment: Should be noted, that if original `Instant` is itself obtained from a `GregorianCalendar`, then original calendar and converted through the `ZonedDateTime` will not be equal (despite having same Epoch-Milli value) - because `GregorianCutover` date will very likely be different.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the TimeZone using the instant and then you can get a calendar.

```
Calendar myCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId))`?

Comment: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2001-12-17T09:30:47Z of type java.time.Instant

Comment: Indeed, you need to specify a ZoneId as well. I updated my answer.