# converting time string to time stamp in java

Tags: java

I have a string of time format
`2015-08-14T06:00:00+08:00`
and I want to convert that to timeStamp but with:

```
public static Long convertTimeStringToTimeStampMilSec(String timeStr){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:SS+08:00");
        try {
            Date d = dateFormat.parse(timeStr);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(d);
            return c.getTimeInMillis();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

And get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:845)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:659)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:585)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:560)
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2597111/3166303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal
>   pattern character 'T'

It should be

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+08:00");
```

Quoted sequences in the format, such a `'T'`, which is treated as a literal.