# Convert DateTime in String to LocalDateTime with TimeZone in Java

Tags: java, java-time

I am trying to convert the **String** which is in the format: **2020-11-23T14:28:45.237Z** to **LocalDateTime** using **DateTimeFormatter** as below:

```
String dateTimeInString = "2020-11-23T14:28:45.237Z";

final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeInString, formatter);
```

But it's giving an exception. Need a guidance on this. Thanks!

Comment: `LocalDateTime` doesn't have timezone information, use `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @ekansh `Z` at the end means `UTC` - for support of time zone you have to use a date-time formats like ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime.

Comment: Your pattern just doesn't match your input string. You're missing the `T` and the `Z` should be an `X` (which handles Z).

Comment: Please always include your exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal pattern character 'T' when parsing a date string to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 2):

`LocalDateTime` doesn't have zone part, you need to use `ZonedDateTime` without `DateTimeFormatter` only in your case, because your `dateTimeInString` can be parsed by the default patter of `ZonedDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

your date time value (**"2020-11-23T14:28:45.237Z"**) have a zone part and you need to use `ZoneDateTime`  to parse zone Date and Time because it because LocaleDateTime doesn't have info about zone:

```
String dateTimeInString = "2020-11-23T14:28:45.237Z";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeInString);
System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: You can very much parse a date string with timezone information into a `LocalDateTime`.