# Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-06-18T23:30:00.000Z"

Tags: android, kotlin, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to format a date and then convert it to a local time , by upon trying it keeps throwing an exception that the data is unparsable , i have attached the code below , if anyone could help , Thank you

- Code that i'm using

```
  fun test() : String {
       val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", 
       Locale.US)
        inputFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
        val date = inputFormat.parse(input)
        val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mma", 
        Locale.US)
        outputFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
        return outputFormat.format(date)
    }
```

Comment: For starters, you're missing the seconds component in your `SimpleDateFormat` string.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you , i ve edited the code but still crashing with same error

Comment: Your inputFormat is still invalid. It needs to be `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")`.

Comment: @DanHarms Thank you it worked , how about converting time to local time , is my code correct ? Thank you

Comment: If it isn't changing the timezone, you can add `outputFormat setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());` prior to formatting.

Comment: @DanHarms I have made a change and time is changing , can you please check one more time ? Thank you

Comment: Only small suggestion is replace "GMT" with "UTC" and use a capital H for hour values. Otherwise, I believe it looks correct but I haven't run it. I'll leave that part to you :).

Comment: @DanHarms Do you mean UTC because of Locale.US ?

Comment: Z == UTC or lack of timezone, whereas GMT is an actual timezone.

Comment: Ah Alright so whenever a date contains Z , it refers to UTC , got it Thank you

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I hand translated your code to Java and got `Jun 18, 2015 07:30PM`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal pattern character 'T' when parsing a date string to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: When I look through the edit history of your question, it seems that you have fixed the error in the code that you originally were asking about. Don’t do that on Stack Overflow. The question is supposed to remain here for future readers to learn from, so they necessarily need to see the bug too.

Comment: @OleV.V. That was not my intention , the other guy who was helping i needed to edit the code so that he can see wether the code is correct or not , that was only my intention . Thank you for understanding .