# Date in java with just year

Tags: java, date, format

My aim is to get a date in the format '{current year}-01-01 00:00:00' i.e. only the value for year changes with time.
What is the best way to do that.

Using

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-01-01 00:00:00");
String format = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```

doesnt seem clean enough.What other options do I have?

Comment: Why use a Date at all? Just curious.

Comment: I need the current year..I thought date was the way to do that..

Comment: Ok. The answers using Calendar are probably the better way. You might also be interested in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136419/get-integer-value-of-the-current-year-in-java).

Comment: If you have found your answer accept the one that has helped you the most so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object. Much easier to manage, and if you need to get to a `date` there are methods for that.

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 //Set to whatever date you want as default
  cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, *year you want*);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Calendar` object with the following code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

Comment: `getInstance()` will give you the current time, including the month, day, hour, minute, etc. `clear()` resets all of those fields, so you get the 1st day of January at midnight for whichever year you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Calendar like this:

```
new GregorianCalendar(Locale.CANADA).get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011,1,1,0,0,0);
```

Then you can change the year of this object with

```
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, [your-int-year]);
```

And print it in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance()
String date = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-01-01 00:00:00"
```