# How to get only the year from DateUtils

Tags: android, date-format, android-date, android-dateutils

How do i get only the year part of a date using DateUtils ? I tried using

```
DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
```

but this seems to return even the month and date.

Comment: How did you use `DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR`? `DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR` is an `int` value used to specify the format when calling `DateUtils.formatDateTime()`.

Comment: DateUtils.formatDateRange(context, date.getTime(), date.getTime(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR);

Comment: Try  `DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, date.getTime(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
   String year = sdf.format(new Date());
```

To take the locale into account use the constructor SimpleDateFormat("template", Locale)

```
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Would this take the locale in account ?

Answer (score 0):

use DateFormat "yyyy", you will get year only

Comment: possible to give a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));   // sdf is SimpleDateFormat
System.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
```

Comment: Create a dateformat like this: 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("your date format");
And in the line c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));, date is your input date in the format you provided when you create the SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @harmjanr he should do that job at least :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136434/1037442)

Answer (score 0):

I've used "YearOf". Seems a bit shorter. Hope it helps:

```
int currentyear = Dateutils::YearOf(Now());
```