# How to get only the year from the Date Class

Tags: android, string, date

Is there a way to get only the year from the `Date` class and parse it into a string?
Here is the code that I use:

```
Date d1 = new Date();
d1.getYear();  `
```

And how to set the date to                    `DatTime.Now`;

like in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474121/i-want-to-get-year-month-day-etc-from-java-date-to-compare-with-gregorian-calen

Comment: nop try it and not working

Comment: post the updated code with the tried version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get integer value of the current year in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136419/get-integer-value-of-the-current-year-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Output:

```
2014
```

Comment: and how to set the date variable to the current date?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getCurrentDate(String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfFrom = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    return (sdfFrom.format(currentTime.getTime()));
}

public static Date getCurrentDate() {
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    return currentTime.getTime();
}

try to use java 8 date
```