# get Year from java.util.Date

Tags: java, cassandra, deprecated, datastax, java.util.date

I have a date column in a Cassandra column family. When I retrieve data from this CF using datastax java API, this date object can be taken as a `java.util.Date` object.

It has a `getYear()` method but it is deprecated. The corresponding javadoc says:

> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.

How can I get the year, month, day attributes from this date object properly?

Comment: If you're getting the value as a `java.util.Date`, what time zone do you want to use for the year? A `Date` is just a point in time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get integer value of the current year in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136419/get-integer-value-of-the-current-year-in-java)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Could you try like tihs;

```
      // create a calendar
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(datetime);  //use java.util.Date object as arguement
      // get the value of all the calendar date fields.
      System.out.println("Calendar's Year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      System.out.println("Calendar's Month: " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
      System.out.println("Calendar's Day: " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

As mentioned in [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html);

> @Deprecated public int getYear() Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1,
>   replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900. Returns a value that
>   is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or
>   begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as
>   interpreted in the local time zone. Returns: the year represented by
>   this date, minus 1900.

Comment: You must set the date before getting the year: `cal.setTime(yourDateObjectFromCassandra);` then you can do `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);`

Comment: @Narmer: No, `Calendar.getInstance()` defaults to the current date/time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep, but the OP wants the year of the Cassandra object, not the current year

Comment: @Narmer: Right, yes - for that case, I see your point. It's also worth noting that `Calendar` will default to the system time zone; it's not clear what time zone the OP wants.

Comment: You are right @Narmer, I answered acording to header of question.

Comment: @SemihEker Thanks, still the locale issue isn't resolved. You should mention that you can initialize your locale through `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.YOUR_COUNTRY);`. I don't think its needed since he wants the year, but its right to mention.

Comment: Oh, the same applies to time zone!

Comment: This works fine, but for dates like  2014-01-05 00:08:00+0530, I get month as 0, what is the reason for this?

Comment: Because months start from 0. January=0, February=1 etc.

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna [January is 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar)

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to use date format as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
Date             date = sdf1.parse(datetime);
String           year = sdf2.format(date);
```

Comment: No need to use `SimpleDateFormat`. `Calendar#get` is fine and faster.

Answer (score 1):

use LocalDate object in java8

```
Date date = new Date();
LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
int year  = localDate.getYear();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
int day   = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the date & time fields you can use this code:

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().getCalendar().get(DateFormat.MONTH_FIELD)
```

Just replace MONTH_FIELD with one somehting else like "DAY_OF_WEEK_FIELD" to retrieve the day of the week (I think '1' stands for monday) or "MINUTE_FIELD" for the current minute, etc. :)