# Date format in java

Tags: java, android

Am getting response as

```
 "pickTime": "Tue Oct 25 03:57 PM"
```

i had coded as follows to get.

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm a");
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd");
                SimpleDateFormat timeFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

String time = jsonObj.optString("pickTime");
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(time); 
String newDateStr = dateFormater.format(dateObj); 
String newTimeStr = timeFormater.format(dateObj);
```

The problem is I am getting same value in String `time` but in dateobj I am getting value as

```
"sun oct 25 15.57 pm"
```

newDatestr as

```
"sun oct 25"
```

Please help me to solve this problem ,thanks in advance

Comment: You'd benefit from a year in your `pickTime` value. Also, check your device's date: the last Sunday 25th October was in 2015.

Comment: i wont receive year in response ,then how i can do it?. As you said i understand that without year,default it taken as 1970,am i correct?

Comment: `pickTime += " " + currentYear`, add it to the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern.

Comment: explain me briefly , what i have to do

Comment: Does pickTime always refer to the current year? What do you expect as result if pickTime is e. g. jan 01 and the current date is 2016 dec 31?

Comment: @mm759 nope,it wont be current year always because if we are in dec 2016,the pickTime may be on 2017.

Comment: @Daryl: You must define how to determine the year. This is about business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It is taking the October 25 of 1970 (Linux time).

You have to figure out how to add the year to the date because it is not taking the current year.

It takes the default one instead (the linux time starts on January 1 1970).

Comment: how to rectify it , year wont be come in response. then is it possible to solve my issue. if it so tell me.

Comment: Yes, use: "int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);" to get the year
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136419/get-integer-value-of-the-current-year-in-java

Comment: thanks for your help.I already done like this.But it wont be current year always because if we are in dec 2016,the pickTime may be on 2017(response).At that time it wont work.

Comment: Then you have to compare the date, if it is greater than the actual one it is a year less.
if( Calendar.getInstance().before(dateCreated) ) { dateCreated.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Your response does not contains year. So you are getting incorrect output.

Below code is working try it out.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm a yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd");
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        String time = "Tue Oct 25 03:57 PM" + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Date dateObj = null;
        try {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Logger.logd(this, dateObj.toString());

        String newDateStr = dateFormater.format(dateObj);
        String newTimeStr = timeFormater.format(dateObj);
        Logger.logd(this, newDateStr + " " + newTimeStr);
```

Comment: thats i know, am asking solution for this without using year in response.

Comment: please see updated comment. I tested and its working

Comment: thanks for your help.I already done like this.But it wont be current year always because if we are in dec 2016,the pickTime may be on 2017(response).At that time it wont work.

Comment: Yes. Then it should have year, otherwise we can not get it.

Comment: Are you sure ,its not possible to get the expected solution without getting year in response side.

Comment: Can you tell me what output you are expecting?

Comment: same as response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126689/discussion-between-daryl-and-subrahmanyam-boyapati).

Answer (score 0):

```
  SimpleDateFormat formatter =new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm a");
     Date date2 = formatter.parse("Tue Oct 25 03:57 PM");
    long time = date2.getTime();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    String formatted = formatter.format(cal.getTime());

    System.out.println(formatted);
```

@David Marciel is right. you should specify year.

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm a");
```

in this why you have put E.

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM dd yyyy hh:mm a");
```

I think this should be format.

Comment: That makes no sence, if the year is not in the datestring