# SimpleDateFormat but with current or next year

Tags: java

I'm trying to adjust my method and accept current year or next if the second part of date is next year.

My code:

```
    private static final String PERIOD = "24 Dec-2 Jan";
    private static DateRange _period = null;

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        _period = DateRange.parse(PERIOD, new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM", Locale.US));
    }
```

And the parse method:

```
    public static DateRange parse(final String dateRange, final DateFormat format)
    {
        final String[] date = dateRange.split("-");

        if (date.length == 2)
        {
            try
            {
                final Date startDate = format.parse(date[0]);
                final Date endDate = format.parse(date[1]);

                return new DateRange(startDate, endDate);
            }
            catch (final ParseException e)
            {
                _log.log(Level.WARNING, "Invalid Date Format.", e);
            }
        }

        return new DateRange(null, null);
    }
```

So after i execute the code i want to have *_startDate* to show *24 Dec 2020* and *_endDate* to show *4 JAN 2021* since is in next year

Edit: Current it print this:

```
Thu Dec 24 00:00:00 EET 1970
Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 EET 1970
```

While i need this

```
Thu Dec 24 00:00:00 EET 2020
Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 EET 2021
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Currently it just parse as it is. Not year. If i system out the startDate it show Sun X X 00:00:00 EET 1970. It was supposed to show Sun X X 00:00:00 EET 2020 and the end date the next year if the month is next year.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated to use Java 8 date APIs. You can find a pre-Java8 version in the revision history.**

You can use Java 8 date APIs to parse a [MonthDay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) (a partial date), set it to the current year (with [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)), and then adjust the years to move the date range to the earliest valid range in the future.

```
public static DateRange parse(final String dateRange, final DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    final String[] dates = dateRange.split("-");
    if (dates.length == 2) {
        try {
            final LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            final int currentYear = now.getYear();
            int startYear = currentYear, endYear = currentYear;
            // Parse partial dates (MonthDay) and set the year to the current year.
            LocalDate startDate = MonthDay.parse(dates[0], formatter).atYear(currentYear);
            LocalDate endDate = MonthDay.parse(dates[1], formatter).atYear(currentYear);
            // Increment both years if the start is in the past.
            if (startDate.isBefore(now)) {
                startYear++;
                endYear++;
            }
            // Increment the end year if the end is before the start.
            if (endDate.isBefore(startDate)) {
                endYear++;
            }
            // Update dates with the years.
            startDate = startDate.withYear(startYear);
            endDate = endDate.withYear(endYear);
            return new DateRange(startDate, endDate);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            _log.log(Level.WARNING, "Invalid Date Format.", e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String dateString = "24 Feb-2 Jan";
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM", Locale.US);
    final DateRange dateRange = parse(dateString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateRange);
}
```

Note that the format is `d MMM` instead of `dd MMM` to support single digit days.

---

Alternatively, if you need to support date strings that include years, you can use a LocalDate solution, and add a default year in the formatter parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String dateString = "24 Feb-2 Jan";
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("d MMM")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now().getValue())
            .toFormatter(Locale.US);
    final DateRange dateRange = parse(dateString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateRange);
}

public static DateRange parse(final String dateRange, final DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    final String[] dates = dateRange.split("-");
    if (dates.length == 2) {
        try {
            final LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            final int currentYear = now.getYear();
            int startYear = currentYear, endYear = currentYear;
            // Parse partial dates (MonthDay) and set the year to the current year.
            LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(dates[0], formatter);
            LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(dates[1], formatter);
            // Increment both years if the start is in the past.
            if (startDate.isBefore(now)) {
                startYear++;
                endYear++;
            }
            // Increment the end year if the end is before the start.
            if (endDate.isBefore(startDate)) {
                endYear++;
            }
            // Update dates with the years.
            startDate = startDate.withYear(startYear);
            endDate = endDate.withYear(endYear);
            return new DateRange(startDate, endDate);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            _log.log(Level.WARNING, "Invalid Date Format.", e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You made a small mistake final int endYear = endNextYear ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear; It's the opposite. But aside that your code is working fine thanks a lot. Is there any java 8 less line way to do that? I mean instead of use 15 lines to do in a shorter way? Thats just for me to check libraries and learn.

Comment: Good catch; I didn't test the code. As for a better way to do this in Java 8, you should use LocalDate instead of Date. Then, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700141/1247781) to get the current year and [LocalDate#withYear](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#withYear-int-) instead of Calendar to set the date.

Comment: By the way sir if my current date has passed for example 14 Feb-4 Jan and now we have 11 May which mean it passed i should add +1 year to start date and +1 year to end date am i right? So it will go 14 Feb 2021 - 4 Jan 2022 right sir?

Comment: I improved your code a bit and increase by 1 year if date is before now 

https://pastebin.com/BMXUHZu5

Comment: @Frye Nice work on the improvement. I updated my answer to use Java 8 APIs. It's not fewer lines necessarily but I find the Java 8 version to be much cleaner. You can also use other Java 8 date APIs like [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) or [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) to use the returned date range depending on your use case. Remember to accept the answer if it helps :)